# Facebook profile information display

Tags: users, social-network

How can i display Facebook profile information like First name, Lastname, address. I am using Drupal for Facebook module in login with facebook a/c in my drupal web site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Facebook OAuth (FBOAuth)](https://www.drupal.org/project/fboauth) module for this. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides authentication services and an API to perform actions against Facebook. This module allows users to login to Drupal through the service commonly known as "Facebook Connect". This module is built with simplicity and flexibility in mind, it provides login services (and does it well), and an API for performing any other actions you may want to write yourself to query against Facebook's APIs.
>
> **Features**:
>
> - One-click login through Facebook.
> - Automatic import of user e-mail and profile information during initial login.
> - Integration with Profile module to map Facebook data to Profile fields. (Drupal 6)
> - Integration with Field module to map Facebook data to fields on users. (Drupal 7)
> - A flexible and direct API for modules to get authenticated and query Facebook's APIs (plus extensive documentation).
> - Extensive permission settings for Facebook data retrieval.
> - The ability to de-authenticate or unlink a Facebook account from a Drupal account.
> - Does not require any external libraries or downloads.

Comment: thax for quick reply abubakar, i will try and let u know the status

Comment: facebook block display like : $user = $facebook->getUser(); $userEmail = $user['email']; print_r($user);

Answer (score 0):

fboauth is best one.i have using that module for user signup.you can easily mapping your facebook information with profile field like religion,email,education history,work history,etc.and the you enable the ADVANCED PERMISSION SETTINGS in toggle tab.